# How to run a Tracker computation only if a specific field of a reactive document changes?

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactive-programming, meteor-tracker

I am using `Tracker.autorun` to call a function in my Meteor app when a collection document is changed. The Tracker is working, however I only want it to run when a specific property of the document is changed :

```
Tracker.autorun(() => {
  let _x = Site.MyCollection.findOne(this._id).myProperty;

  if (_x) {
    this._myMethod(_x);
  }
});
```

I only want the computation to invalidate when the value of 'myProperty' changes, however it's called whenever any property of the collection is updated.

I can't use `Session` variables in this case, because the value of `myProperty` could be updated by another connected client.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `myProperty` isn't reactive. The object on which it is defined is.
If you want to keep a nice reactivity then you could use a `ReactiveVar` to store the value of `myProperty`, then use a computation to update its value.

```
var myProperty = new ReactiveVar();

Tracker.autorun(function() {
  //Reactivity kicks in with findOne
  myProperty.set(
    Site.MyCollection.findOne(this._id).myProperty
  )
})
```

You can then run a reactive computation on `myProperty`.

Note that while the above code sets `myProperty` all the time and thus may seem to trigger reactivity each time, it will actually ignore the cases in which the old value is `===` to the new value.
If you find this behaviour undesirable you can forcefully invalidate registered dependencies :

```
//'_dependentsById' is an array-like object lacking an iterator, fallback on _
_.each(myProperty.dep._dependentsById, 
  (dep) => dep.invalidate()
)
```

Comment: Great, thanks for the explanation. Will work on that today.